# Provisional Push Permissions not updated after pressing keep, iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, authorization, push

We recently developed the provisional permission for our app, but we have noticed that is not working as expected in iOS 16 (We have tested only there). Currently we request the permissions like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound, .provisional]) { [weak self] _, _ in

           // here we register for pushes in case authorizationStatus is provisional or authorised

        }
```

What happens is we do get the 1st notification with the keep CTA - once tapped we see that there pops an action: "Deliver Immediately", but even though the user selects that, we still see under setting the pushes are marked as "Deliver Quietly". In addition to this the sound and bage still stay as toggled off - and the lock screen and banner as well stay off.
Basically, nothing changes after the user selects "Deliver Immediately"

I tried multiple times in iOS 16 but same result. Is there a change on the behaviour or a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Having the same issue on my end, after sending a provisional push, and user accepted it with "deliver immediately", notification center "Sound" and "Badge" toggles stay off and there is no way to re-request this access. Any luck solving this issue?